# Python XML Parsing throwing FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'file.xml'

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am trying to parse through the entire Blog Authorship Corpus for text processing(consisting of XML files) and load it into a single Pandas dataframe for further analysis. I am using 'xml.etree.cElementTree' library for this purpose. But while parsing it is throwing the aforementioned error message. Kindly find my code snippet below :

The code is able to find the path and read the XML file, because it returns the id and age variables from inside the loop

```
def blog_authorship(datapath):
    if not os.path.exists(datapath):
        print('ERROR : This path does not exist !!')
    else:
        columns = ['id', 'gender', 'age', 'industry', 'astrological sign', 
'date', 'post']
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        for filename in os.listdir(datapath):
            if filename.endswith('.xml'):
                id, gender, age, industry, astrological_sign, _ = 
os.path.basename(filename).split('.')
                print(id, age)
                parsedXML = et.parse(filename)
                for node in parsedXML.getroot():
                    date = node.find('date')
                    post = node.find('post')
                    dataframe = dataframe.append(pd.Series([id, gender, age, 
industry, astrological_sign, date.text, post.text], index=columns), 
ignore_index=True)
    print(dataframe)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Setting the arguments for the Speech to Text model')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--datapath', required=True, default='', help='The path containing the xml files containing the data')
    args = parser.parse_args(['-f', r'C:\Mypath\blogs'])

    blog_authorship(args.datapath)
```

Comment: What it prints if you try to print parsedXML.getroot()?

Comment: I tried printing that out, it's throwing the exact same error as above.

Comment: A guess: change `parsedXML = et.parse(filename)` to `parsedXML = et.parse(os.path.join(datapath, filename))`.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks a lot. It works now, throwing some other error though !!